# how to read a file from command line, then output a file with the same name but different extension in python

Tags: python

I want to read a file from command line first, then run my script and output a file with a different extension.

for example:
if I do python script.py apple.java
there should be an output file called banana.md

I do not want to rename the file. 
Dont worry about path or anything.

```
n= sys.argv[-1]
base = os.path.splitext(n)[0]


os.rename(n,base + ".md")
```

Comment: *The code I wrote now is keep on renaming the existing file :(* - Show it.

Comment: I do not want to use my code to confuse others..But whatever, i put it on now

Comment: surprisingly, os.rename is renaming the file :-D

Comment: `shutil.copy(n, "{}.md".format(n.rsplit(".",1)[0]))`

Comment: I am not copying a file...I am working on a script to convert a json file to a markdown file. I have already finished the script. The only thing I need to do is to change the extension

Comment: "I do not want to rename the file. So both apple.java and apple.md should be there", how is that not copying?

Answer (score 0):

you can copy the file : you can use [shutil.copyfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) which will do the job just fine.

or you can just try to read it and write it:

```
with open (input,'r') as in:
    with open(output,'w') as out:
        out.write(in.read())
```

Comment: would that copy the whole file? I do not want to copy file cause I am writing a script to convert one file to another

Comment: how would I specify and change extension there?